# How to select all nth descendants of a node using xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have a tree like this.

```
<div class="root">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div> <--- select this
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div> <--- and select this
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the xpath `//*[contains(@class, 'root')]/descendant::*[3]` but it only selects the first one. How do I write an xpath that selects all nth descendants without having to do `*/*/*/*...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the elements whose depth is three levels below the context item, you want `./*/*/*`. If "three" here is a variable rather than a known constant then it becomes more difficult - and almost impossible in XPath 1.0 (which is what people usually want if they don't specify an XPath version).

In XPath 2.0+ you could write `$x/descendant::*[ancestor::*[$level] is $x]`

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0 you could use:

```
descendant::*[count(ancestor::div[not(@class='root')])=2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.

```
 //*[contains(@class, 'root')]/*/descendant::*[2]
   ^                           ^             ^
   |                           |             |
Root                           |             |
     All direct children of root             |
       Grandchild of each direct child of root
```

Comment: Wrong answer (you didn't generate enough test cases). descendant::*[2] doesn't select grandchildren. It selects the second node among all the descendants, at any level.